# Plotting a barchart over a histogram in R

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to overlay a histogram with a stacked barplot, yet the barplot is always shifted to the right as it starts plotting from zero. See below for an example on what I am trying to do (without using ggplot, I should maybe add).

```
set.seed(1)

dat <- rnorm(1000, sd = 10)
h <- hist(dat)
cnt <- h$counts
breaks <- h$breaks

mat <- matrix(NA, nrow = 3, ncol = length(cnt))
for(i in 1:length(cnt)){
  sample <- sample(1:3, size = cnt[i], replace = TRUE)
  for(j in 1:3){
    mat[j, i] <- sum(sample == j)
  }
}

barplot(mat, add = TRUE, width = unique(diff(breaks)), space = 0, 
        col = c("blue", "green", "orange"))
```

The output from this code looks as follow:

[image]

I have tried using columnnames in the matrix mat which specify the position, but to no avail. In the plot I want to create the histogram will be overplotted entirely, as it should be in the exact same place as the barplot. The reason for plotting it in the first place is that I want the axis that a histogram plot gives me. Any ideas on how to do this are very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may combine the bar mids of `barplot` console output and breaks of `hist` to create `axis` ticks; subtract half of barplot widths from the bar mids. Using `mtext` gives a better control for the axis labels.

```
h <- hist(dat, plot=FALSE)
# [...]

.width <- unique(diff(breaks))
b <- barplot(mat, width=.width, space=0, 
        col=c("blue", "green", "orange"))
axis(1, b-.width/2, labels=FALSE)
mtext(h$breaks[-length(h$breaks)], 1, 1, at=b-.width/2)
```

[image]

### Edit

```
.width <- unique(diff(breaks))
b <- barplot(mat, width=.width, space=0, 
             col=c("blue", "green", "orange"))
ats <- seq(0, par()$usr[2], 5)
mod <- (ats + 5) %% 20 == 0
labs <- h$breaks
axis(1, ats[mod], labels=FALSE)
mtext(labs[mod], 1, 1, at=ats[mod])
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot! I will look into this, the only negative is that the x axis looks a bit less nice than in the histogram plot. But I guess I should look at the source code of "hist" and have a look how they determine the axis tick marks and see if I can use that

Comment: @Annylowell There's another way hacking the `par()$usr`, see edit to my answer.

Comment: awesome! I actually used the par()$xaxp to then give those arguments to axis and mtext. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

I would just set a manual x axis to the barplot with the desired labels at the desired position, like this:

```
barplot(mat, width = unique(diff(breaks)),space = 0,  
        col = c("blue", "green", "orange"))
axis(1,at=c(15,35,55,75),labels = c(-20,0,20,40))
```

[image]

Comment: thanks! However, while that works in this particular case, I would want to use something along those lines inside a function, so I need a way to have this done automatically. One option would be to "extract" the x axis values from the histogram, save them, and them plot them for the bar plot but as those values do not seem to be saved as a histogram attribute I did not manage to do that either.